# Eclipse: search for the text in Java class comments etc

Tags: java, eclipse, class, search, rad

I want to search for the text that is written in annotations and comments in my java classes. e.g

```
/** 
 * Object interface mapping for hibernate-handled table: mytable.
 * @author
 */

public interface myInterface{
}
```

I tried to search `mytable` in eclipse "java search" and "file search" but it not searching these texts and I can see these texts in annotaions etc.

I also use java search option match location and select all but it still did not search for **mytable**.

Please tell me how to do it in eclipse or RAD 8.0 (if possible).

After search how to replace that without opening each file?

Comment: do you have source code or you want to search in class file or jar?

Comment: i always customize my search and only select File Search. It's the best, assuming you've specified the right file filters.

Comment: then it will work, see my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do *file search* on all `*.java` files in the current workspace/the project with keyword `mytable`, then this file (`myInterface.java`) should be in the search result. That's how it's supposed to work.

Comment: After search how to replace that without opening each file?

Comment: The search dialog provides three buttons: "Replace...", "Search" and "Cancel". Simply use "Replace...", this builds the search result lists and asks for the replacement string. Eclipse will do the replace for you.

Answer (score 2):

it do,

eclipse searches that string under

> Search->File search-> Comtaining
>   text:mytable

file pattern *.java

it works for java file

Comment: After search how to replace that without opening each file?

Answer (score 1):

For searching the text from any file you can use file search option it should work

Comment: After search how to replace that without opening each file?

Comment: @imran check the Andreas_D comment

Answer (score 0):

for searching in annotations, there is an option "Limit To" on the "Java search" tab for searching only in annotation text.
however I couldn't find a match location for comments, which I'd need just now...